# Visual Studio - Tie up database imported to project

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio

I am currently working on MySQL and I have imported the database to Visual Studio (Windows Form - c#). When I try to tie up the database to the project I cannot "add a new source of data".

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise from my Azure student account.

Maybe someone faced the same problem.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Open Visual Studio Installer => Modify. Click "Workloads". Ensure that the "Data storage and processing" workload is installed (or at least "Individual components => Data sources and service references)

Comment: Also see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/